# AppScript Dropdown Menu from other sheet with filtered results

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I explain what I'm trying to do with appscript:
I need a function that creates a dropdown menu in cell `A1` of "Sheet1" where the values are taken from "column D" of "Sheet2", but only where in the corresponding row of "column C" is written `"Pending"` or `"Open"`.

I figured out how to create the dropdown menu but I'm struggling with how to filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

A function to create a dataValidation in columnA of sheet1 when column C in same row is either Pending or Open.  DataValidation values coming from sheet2 column D

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const a = ["Pending","Open"];
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && ~a.indexOf(e.value)) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(osh.getRange(1,4,osh.getLastRow())).build();
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setDataValidation(r)
  }
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."